# Cloud Scheduler return not executed function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I've a problem with google cloud Scheduler. the algorithm api is written in aspnet core and return the corret status code 200 but the google console return this:

```
{ "targetType": "HTTP", "status": "INTERNAL", "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName": "projects/prj-296906/locations/europe-west1/jobs/algoritmo", "url": "https://myprovide/api/algorithm/algorithm" }
```

any idea? thanks

Comment: How long take your URL call to answer?

Comment: This seems to be standard log item. What makes you think something is wrong?